# Azure Data Factory v2 intermittent error while calling stored procedure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Running Azure Data Factory v2 with a for each loop with a batch count of 4-8. Calling several stored procedures and 1 copy activity. Targets are all the same Azure SQL Database. Running this setup for ~8 months in production.

Suddenly this week acceptance started to fail intermittently on calling the stored procedures. Production since last night (2019-09-05). All with the same error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "USP_End_Batch_Successful"
}
```

There is no pattern. Rerunning the pipeline results in failing other parts of the for-each loop. Setting the batch count lower, no improvement. Load on the database is not high. Log analytics on the databases show no blocks, deadlocks, dropped connections etc. Even the most stripped and basic stored procedures fail. No data on the database is changed at all.

The retry option will not work: the option is set to 1, and the stored procedure is not re-run.

Any clue how to dig further into this problem or any solution?

Example activity run id: 033ca5ab-c396-407f-8362-794459e4d0c4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause a few days later: we had a job running that was scaling the database during our ETL window. Hence running queries got killed at some point, resulting in the error above.